# SPARQL query:Get the class and the data property related to a given String Literal

Tags: sparql, owl

I want to construct a SPARQL query to retrieve the class and the data property related to a given String , as an exemple the user input is "Jhon",the result is Person->Name->"Jhon".
where the class is Person ,Data property is Name.
Can you please Help me to do this I am just a beginner in this field.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: then just create a SPARQL `SELECT` query with the single triple pattern where predicate is the property URI and object is the string literal value. And you simply select the subject of the triple pattern.

Comment: @UninformedUser thanks for the reply,but in my case both subject and Predicate are unknown

Comment: you said "Dataproperty is Name", so why is it unknown? Which RDF triples are in the dataset, what information exists to build the query and what is the expected result? Please provide only RDF triples as SPARQL is a query language for RDF. Any textual description is too vague and makes it too confusing.

Comment: And if you just have the object as a string, then just use a triple pattern with subject and predicate being a variable and the object being the string literal.